# React Leaflet LayerGroup.Collision Plugin

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

This is my component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { MapLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import './collision.js';

export default class LayerGroupCollision extends MapLayer {
  static childContextTypes = {
    layerContainer: PropTypes.shape({
      addLayer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      removeLayer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    })
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      layerContainer: this.leafletElement,
    }
  }
  createLeafletElement() {
    var t = L.layerGroup.collision({ margin: 20 }, this.getOptions());
    this.layerContainer.addLayer(t);
    return t;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {map} = this.context;
    map.on("zoomend", this._onZoomEnd);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const {map} = this.context;
    map.off("zoomend", this._onZoomEnd);
  }
}
```

But this do not work, i just get the markers.
And on zoom i get error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>
> ```
> at NewClass.fire (leaflet-src.js:587)
> at NewClass._moveEnd (leaflet-src.js:3432)
> at NewClass.<anonymous> (leaflet-src.js:3869)
> ```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define `_onZoomEnd` function in your class and MapLayer class which you extend from doesn't have it neither.
But in `map.on("zoomend", this._onZoomEnd)` and `map.off("zoomend", this._onZoomEnd)` you provide it as a callback for the zoomend event.
Then it fails to call _onZoomEnd because it is undefined

Comment: I do understand, using this._onZoomEnd i try use it ftom leaflet-layergroup-collision, on debugge when i zoom this method runs.
Sorry for inconvience, here the link at github if you can help me please.
https://github.com/Shadowman4205/react-leaflet-layergroup-collision

Answer (score 0):

The plugin itself takes care of defining the listeners, so you can omit that code.  The below code should be sufficient for wrapping the Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision plugin in a React component.  Alex's comment is correct for the reason you were getting the error message.

```
import React from 'react';
import { func, shape } from 'prop-types';
import { MapLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet.layergroup.collision';
import L from 'leaflet';

export default class LayerGroupCollision extends MapLayer {
  static childContextTypes = {
    layerContainer: shape({
      addLayer: func.isRequired,
      removeLayer: func.isRequired,
    }),
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      layerContainer: this.leafletElement,
    };
  }

  createLeafletElement() {
    const layerGroup = L.layerGroup.collision({ margin: 4 });
    this.layerContainer.addLayer(layerGroup);
    return layerGroup;
  }
}
```